# Get `git commit -a` to ignore submodules?

Tags: git

The behaviour of `git commit -a` seems to be to include changes to submodules, if they have new commits inside them. This isn't what I normally want, and I sometimes find myself accidentally pushing a commit with submodule changes that I didn't intend to include.

Is there a way to set `git commit -a` to ignore submodules? I had a look in `git help config` and didn't see anything.

A (less good) alternative might be to get `git status` to make it clearer at a glance whether `git commit -a` would include a submodule. Currently it shows either

```
modified:   submodule (modified content)
```

or

```
modified:   submodule (new commits)
```

and those are annoyingly similar. It looks like the `submodule.<name>.ignore` config option can do something like what I want. But ideally I'd still like to see changes to submodules, just not in the same place as all my other changes unless `git commit -a` will add them.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the submodule.ignore in git config or in the .gitmodules file.

NOTE: GIT is kind of stupid with this. If you set ignore = all, to get sane behavior with git commit -a, it will ALSO ignore the submodule in git show/diff when you EXPLICITLY add them. The only way to work-around the latter is using the command line option --ignore-submodule=none.

NOTE2: The diff.ignoreSubmodules config is supposed to be able to set the default command line option --ignore-submodule, but has been broken for years, and does nothing as .gitmodules wins the contest, so only explicit command line options will get you sane behavior.

Comment: Where exactly do you use ` --ignore-submodule=none` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a ton of submodules, what I found the most convenient is to first commit all, then run

> git reset HEAD^1 submodule_path

You can always get a reminder of this command syntax if you run git commit --amend without any change. It will show up near the top of the commented instructions.